# Sitecore User Group - Budapest #7

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**About the event:**

**LIVE STREAM!**

The seventh Hungarian Sitecore User Group has been announced! This meetup is going to be a special one! 3 presentations with 3 presenters from 3 countries! They will talk about the following topics:

- Offline tracking with the Sitecore Universal Tracker - Akshay Sura (@Partner at Konabos Consulting & Sitecore MVP)
- Editors and Developers on the fast lane - Rendering variants and snippets in SXA - Sebastian Winter (@METRONOM & Sitecore MVP)
- Extend Sitecore Commerce Engine - Vlad Iobagiu (@Freelancer & Sitecore Commerce MVP)

Free conversations, pizza and drink after the presentations.

**When (UTC):** Tuesday, February 5, 2018 6:00 PM

**Where:** POSSIBLE CEE Budapest, Bocskai út 134-146.
Budapest, Hungary 1113

**[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Budapest/events/257037952/)**

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins in 3 days